# Asyncio exception handling, possible to not gather exceptions?

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, exception, python-asyncio

I have some code, which makes some API calls with `asyncio` and `aiohttp`. For some urls, asyncio will raise an exception, so I allow it to return it (with `asyncio.gather(return_exceptions = True)`), so it doesn't break the event loop. Is it possible to no gather the returned exceptions, so it returns only the results which worked? Or do I need to clean up the list manually afterwards?

This is the code:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import ssl
import datetime as dt

limit = 30
start_epoch = int(dt.datetime(2018,7,1).timestamp())
end_epoch = int(dt.datetime.now().timestamp())
epoch_step = 40000
url_list = []
while True:
    url = "https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/comment/?q=" + "Nestle" + "&size=" + str(limit) + "&after=" + str(start_epoch) + "&before=" + str(start_epoch + epoch_step)
    url_list.append(url)
    start_epoch += epoch_step
    if start_epoch > end_epoch:
        break

async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url, ssl=ssl.SSLContext()) as response:
        return await response.json()


async def fetch_all(urls, loop):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        results = await asyncio.gather(*[fetch(session, url) for url in urls], return_exceptions=True)
        return results


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    urls = url_list
    htmls = loop.run_until_complete(fetch_all(urls, loop))
    print(htmls)
```

and it returns a list which looks something like this:

```
[ContentTypeError("0, message='Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype: text/html'",), {'data': [{'author':...]
```

Comment: If `gather` omitted the exception results altogether, how would you know which result came from which URL? The contract of `gather` is that it returns a list containing as many results as there are coroutines you gave it, and in the same order.

Comment: @user4815162342 I wouldn't. At this point I don't really care which URL works and which didn't

Comment: @Jannik you can write something like this `for val in htmls: if issubclass(val, Exception): skip_it` and also you can catch exception in `fetch` function and return empty list.

Comment: It's not only about caring which one works and which one doesn't, but also about which results belong to which URL. `gather` preserves order so you can match return values with coroutines that produced them, and filtering out the exceptions would remove that possibility (and also silence the exceptions, which is an anti-pattern on its own). Fortunately filtering the results to exclude exceptions is straightforward: `results = [v for v in await asyncio.gather(...) if not (isinstance(v, type) and issubclass(v, Exception))]`